# resource linking failed not found. error: failed linking file resources

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Android resource linking failed

```
C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Compressed\FlashLightAppl\app\src\main\res\menu\option_menu.xml:3: error: resource color/Black (aka com.cherrytechstudio.flashlightappl:color/Black) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

no result were Error

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);//Menu ResourceFile
        return true;
```

Comment: need to add color in colors.xml with `Black` name

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code but if you referencing a color in xml in AndroidStudio you will have to format it properly for example:

```
<Button
...
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to colors.xml and create black. I give you more colors if you need. Also you can reference by @android:color/Black.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

If the problem persists, try to clean projecta and sync.

I hope It helps you!